# Can't parse a Google search result page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, google-search

I'm parsing webpages using BeautifulSoup from bs4 in python. When I inspected the elements of a google search page, the first division had `class  = 'r'` I wrote this code:

```
import requests
site = requests.get('<url>')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
results = page.find_all('div', class_="r")
print(results)
```

But the command prompt returned just `[]`

What could've gone wrong and how to correct it?

**EDIT 1:** I edited my code accordingly by adding the dictionary for headers, yet the result is the same `[]`.
Here's the new code:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
}
site = requests.get('<url>', headers = headers)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
results = page.find_all('div', class_="r")
print(results)
```

**NOTE:** When I tell it to print the entire page, there's no problem, or when I take `list(page.children)` , it works fine.

Comment: You'll need to pass `User-Agent` header to the `requests.get` as an optional parameter with `headers=headers` where headers is a dictionary of **http request headers**

Comment: so I should change the 2nd line to: site = requests.get('[page link]', headers = headers)              ?

Comment: Yes, with the `headers` being a dictionary of headers

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by dictionary? A link for explanation, maybe?

Comment: Like `{'User-Agent': '[Stuff]'}`. Also, you can get Firefox/Chrome user agent on the mozilla webpage

Comment: I still don't understand it. However, let me read up on it. I'll get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Some website requires `User-Agent` header to be set to prevent **fake** request from non-browser. But, fortunately there's a way to pass headers to the request as such

```
# Define a dictionary of http request headers
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
} 

# Pass in the headers as a parameterized argument
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

**Note:** List of user agents can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: @saumayr Weird. Mine worked just fine. Try to print `site.content` and see if the `div`s are in there at all

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> give_me_everything = soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf')
Prints a bunch of stuff.
>>> give_me_everything_v2 = soup.select('.yuRUbf')
Prints a bunch of stuff.
```

Note that you can't do something like this:

```
>>> give_me_everything = soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf').text
AttributeError: You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element.
```

```py
>>> for all in soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf'):
    print(all.text)
Prints a bunch of stuff.
```

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    "Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q="narendra modi" "scams" "frauds" "corruption" "modi" -lalit -nirav', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

give_me_everything = soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf')
print(give_me_everything)
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

The main difference is that you don't have to come with a different solution when something isn't working thus don't have to maintain the parser.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": 'narendra modi" "scams" "frauds" "corruption" "modi" -lalit -nirav',
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    title = result['title']
    link = result['link']
    displayed_link = result['displayed_link']
    print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{displayed_link}\n')

----------
Opposition Corners Modi Govt On Jay Shah Issue, Rafael ...
https://www.outlookindia.com/website/story/no-confidence-vote-opposition-corners-modi-govt-on-jay-shah-issue-rafael-deals-c/313790
https://www.outlookindia.com

Modi, Rahul and Kejriwal describe one another as frauds ...
https://www.business-standard.com/article/politics/modi-rahul-and-kejriwal-describe-one-another-as-frauds-114022400019_1.html
https://www.business-standard.com
...
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.